# Why do i need to set IsRequired if it comes from class?

Tags: wcf

I'm having trouble to understand the situation which Is :

The Host has a service which has operationMethods
for example `Calc (Myclass a)`

`MyClass` contains 2 properties ( `prop1` , `prop2`)

Now , the clients also whould know about `MyClass` via proxy and should know also  contract by reference.

So when the client creates new instance of MyClass (to send it)- **how can one prop can be missing** ???

when he instancing new MyClass - both prop are initialized (null or what ever). so **why do i need the isRequired** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres no guarantee as to what language or how they are formulating their soap request, so the way they are generating it may not use a generated class that contains the property. Is required requires that is present in the message

Interaction with IsRequired

As discussed in Data Contract Versioning, the DataMemberAttribute attribute has an IsRequired property (the default is false). The property indicates whether a given data member must be present in the serialized data when it is being deserialized. If IsRequired is set to true, (which indicates that a value must be present) and EmitDefaultValue is set to false (indicating that the value must not be present if it is set to its default value), default values for this data member cannot be serialized because the results would be contradictory. If such a data member is set to its default value (usually null or zero) and a serialization is attempted, a SerializationException is thrown.

Comment: so if a user instancing MyCLass with null properties  values - this will cause an exception ?

Comment: its not exactly null values that it prevents, but nonexistence in the incoming soap packet.

Comment: when he instancing new MyClass - both prop are initialized (null or what ever) - so it can never be missing...??

Comment: Sure if you instantiate it and send it using the generated c# service client. But what if you are creating the soap message using some other technology?

Comment: i dont get it : if a user Want to send me an object of Myclass - so he should probably know what its properties ? are you talking about human mistake case ?

Comment: Thats one possibility, don't forget that anything can communicate with your service. They might be assembling the soap packets with their own custom code for all you know and who knows what rules they are using to create the packet...